# template specialization and default template parameters and sfinae

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae, specialization, default-template-argument

I have put together an example on creating a base template with a number of specializations.

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T, typename U = void>
struct foo {
    static void apply() {
        std::cout << "a: " << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }
};

template<typename U>
struct foo<int, U> {
    static void apply() {
        std::cout << "b: " << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }
};

template<typename U>
struct foo<double, U> {
    static void apply() {
        std::cout << "c: " << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }
};

template<>
struct foo<double, double> {
    static void apply() {
        std::cout << "d: " << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }
};

template<typename T>
struct foo<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T, char>>> {
    static void apply() {
        std::cout << "e: " << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }
};

template<>
struct foo<short> {
    static void apply() {
        std::cout << "f: " << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }
};

template<>
struct foo<unsigned long, void> {
    static void apply() {
        std::cout << "g: " << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    foo<long>::apply();
    foo<long, long>::apply();
    foo<int>::apply();
    foo<int, int>::apply();
    foo<double>::apply();
    foo<double, float>::apply();
    foo<double, double>::apply();
    foo<char>::apply();
    foo<short>::apply();
    foo<unsigned long>::apply();

    return 0;
}
```

When a specialization is defined and a template parameter is defined in the base template such as the template parameter U which is defaulted to void how is this propagated to the specializations. Is the done at the point of specialization as in the first specialization foo<int, U> and U must be void as it is unspecified and adopted from the base template?

Also with the

```
template<typename T>
struct foo<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T, char>>>
```

specialization, the enable_if_t yields the type void, why does this not collide with the base template and how is it considered more specialized?

Any additional quotes from the standard to complement answers are additionally welcome.

Comment: if I understand the quesiton correctly you need 1 or 2 specializations in the example only

Answer (score 0):

Default template arguments affect **all** template argument lists where their template parameter is not otherwise specified.  That means that

```
template<>
struct foo<short>
```

is an explicit specialization of `foo<short,void>` just as `foo<short>::apply()` is a use of that specialization.  It even applies to template argument **deduction**:

```
template<class T>
void bar(foo<T>);
```

deduces `T` from an argument of type `foo<T,void>`.  (This is more interesting in the case where the default depends on `T` and users sometimes supply something else.)

Similarly,

```
template<class T>
struct foo<T*>  // not from the question's code
```

is a partial specialization of `foo<T*,void>`.  Of course, one major use of default template arguments is to provide a **SFINAE** hook, as in the case of

```
template<typename T>
struct foo<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T, char>>>
```

Here, `foo<char>` matches this specialization because it's really `foo<char,void>`; it's possible to use the primary template instead by writing (say) `foo<char,const void>`, but clients are usually expected not to do that (sometimes by providing a type alias that exposes only the intended template parameter).  Under that assumption, the specializations

```
template<>
struct foo<double, double>
```

is **useless** and

```
template<typename U>
struct foo<double, U>
```

is just the same as

```
template<>
struct foo<double>
```

except that the latter is not a **template** (so that errors are sometimes reported earlier and `typename` isn't needed for dependent names).

The determination that it is more **specialized** than the primary template does not involve the default template argument: it is based on trying to deduce `T` from `foo<T,U>`, not `foo<T/*,void*/>` ([temp.spec.partial.order]/1.2).